# Оптимизация поиска по БД: надо ли делать и как

Tags: база-данных, оптимизация, sql

Нужно искать в БД следующим образом: 
 - по строке объекта из справочника найти запись, которая ссылается на этот объект (проект данного менеджера)
 - по интервалу дат с точностью до дня или месяца (проекты за последний месяц) 
 - по их объединению

Я придумал следующие гениальные оптимизации:

1. Не делаем нормализации, пишем строку из справочника сразу в нашу таблицу. тогда при получении результатов поиска нам не надо делать `join`, однако придется искать по строке, а не по `id`, вероятно такой индекс дороже стоит, хотя можно наверное записать и то и то, и искать по `id`.
2. Запоминаем дату как число дней с какой-то даты. Тогда можно будет искать по `int`, а не по дате, что (возможно) быстрее.

Есть ли смысл заниматься такими делами? Понимаю, что все зависит от нагрузки и не надо ничего преждевременно оптимизировать, тут спрашиваю просто про то возможен ли именно такой путь оптимизации, будет ли выигрыш, если заменить поиск до строке или дате на поиск по `int`.

Comment: Какая цель оптимизации ? Вы просто так решили или реально есть в этом необходимость? Если последнее, тогда проанализируйте что конкретно работает медленнее чем ожидалось и тогда уже решайте эту проблему поставив перед собой реальную цель.

Comment: В дополнение к индексу по ID в справочнике Вам еще индекс по датам может оказатья полезным. 

А вообще, не видя списка запросов (с их относительной частотой и требованиями к времени отклика) толком тут ничего не посоветовать.

Прежде чем заниматься предлагаемой Вами "оптимизацией" неплохо было бы попытаться настроить "стандартно нормализованную" систему.

Comment: Да вы правы, заранее этого делать не надо, мне просто интересно было узнать могут ли сработать   ухищрения которые я описал.

Comment: А ну это типично для программиста, когда есть знание и хочется их куда-то приложить. Тут важно понимать что иногда чем проще решение тем лучше (хотя бы тем что потом кому-то придется разбиратся с чем как это работает). Понимаете, нет предела совершенству, пока у вас нет реальной "планки" к чему надо стремится (т.е желаемого быстродействия) оптимизировать глупо. Т.к. вы никогда не добьетесь совершенства. Ведь нет цели, а значит ее достичь невозможно...

p.s. не забывайте что чем больше кода тем больше возможности спрятатся багу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нормализация придумана не просто так. Ответьте себе на 1 простой вопрос: что будет с вашим поиском если значение в справочнике поменяется?

**P.S.** Если значение в справочнике никогда не меняется - то справочник ли это?

Comment: Ну на самом деле вполне может быть справочник где значения не меняются - список стран, к примеру. Но даже если поменялось - то что? Придется пройти по всем местам где оно используется и заменить. А можно оставить таблицу-справочник, но одновременно хранить значение из справочника в других таблицах чтобы не делать join. Тогда при изменении значения придется лишь найти записи по id-справочника и изменить там поле значение-справочника.

Comment: избегать join  следует только по религиозным причинам. других противопоказаний нет

Comment: Список стран это все равно ничего не доказывает - а если потребуется локализовать список стран или Кыргызтан переименуется в Кыргызжер (а они вроде собираются)? Ну и т.д. Если построены правильные индексы то `join` нормальная операция и всяко-разно получше вашей гениальной оптимизации

Comment: ok, спасибо. А вообще есть разница при поиске по строковому индексу, или по численному, или по датам? Имею ввиду, можно ли утверждать что поиск по какому-то из этих типов индексов быстрее, чем по другим?

Comment: нет разницы... В оконцове индекс любого типа сводится `int/long/bigint`

Comment: Пусть более посвященные меня поправят, но представление о БД современных серверов, как о совокупности файлов по 1 штуке на таблицу несколько наивно

Comment: @renegator вы хотите сказать что запрос с JOIN'ом это 1о чтение hd?

Comment: тогда договоримся о терминах - что такое 1 чтение hd

Comment: Опуская последнее замечание, не имеющее отношения к предмету, можно придти к заключению, что тезис о двух чтениях и мельтешения с дескрипторами ложен

Comment: @renegator я так и не понял, вы хотите сказать, что денормализация таблицы не дает прироста производительности?

Если у ТСа возникают такие вопросы, то она ему не нужна, не спорю, но суть не в этом

Comment: @renegator это очень наивное утверждение: 1 таблица=1 файл

Answer (score 1):

> 1) не делаем нормализации, пишем строку из справочника сразу в нашу таблицу. тогда при получении результатов поиска нам не надо делать join, однако придется искать по строке, а не по id, вероятно такой индекс дороже стоит, хотя можно наверное записать и то и то, и искать по id.

В случае одной таблицы (без нормализации) потребуется один индекс - по вашему строковому полю. В случае со справочником потребуется индекс в справочнике (поиск ID по строке) и индекс в основной таблице (по полю соединения со справочником).

При этом JOIN по индексированным полям стоит дешево, поэтому использовать нормализацию или нет не стоит определять по производительности одного этого запроса. Например, если у вас выводится список стран где-либо, тогда вам точно нужен справочник.

> 2) запоминаем дату как число дней с какой-то даты. тогда можно будет искать по int, а не по дате, что (возможно) быстрее.

Дата тоже хранится как число тиков, прошедших с определенного момента. Поэтому это не будет быстрее.